# Scraping a HTML table using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have a written a code for scraping a HTML table by using python selenium.
but the issue is, it was returning an empty object from which I was written.  Thank you.  I can scrape any values but not in the table. I have tried on td, tr, span tags. those returning empty object

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
import pyodbc 
import datetime
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode
import sys
import re


reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

browser =  webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.cbsl.gov.lk/measures-of-consumer-price-inflation")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
bs_obj = BSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
table  = bs_obj.findAll('table')

print(table)
```

Comment: Have you ever viewed the source of that URL? There are no `table` tags.

Comment: yes. I can Scrape any values but not in the table. I have tried <td>, <span>, <tr> those tags not returning values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas` library to get `Consumer Price Inflation` table data.

Inspect webpage, you will see `Consumer Price Inflation` table data inside iframe and it's source url is `https://www.cbsl.gov.lk/cbsl_custom/inflation/inflationwindow.php` and not required `selenium` library to **scrape** data. you can also get table data by `requests` library with pandas, it's response time less then `selenium` library.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.cbsl.gov.lk/cbsl_custom/inflation/inflationwindow.php"
res = requests.get(url)
tables = pd.read_html(res.text)

print(tables[0])
```